# Segmentation fault in parsing

Tags: c, parsing, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to build a code that would convert HTML into text file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BUFLEN 2048

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("tc.txt", "r");
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char storage[BUFLEN];
    char title[100];

    fread(storage, 1, sizeof(storage), fp);
    for(i=0; storage[i]; i++){
         if(storage[i] == '<' && storage [i+1] == 't'){
                for(i=i+7; storage[i] != '<'; j++){
                        title[j] = storage[i];
                }
         }
    }
    puts(title);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is to look for the <title> block in an html(converted to txt file) then copy whatever comes after until the program reaches '<', which signifies the </title> block.

However, when I run the program, segmentation fault occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I suspect that your Seg Fault may be coming from your last for loop.

`for( i=i+7; storage[i] != '<'; j++ ){
    title[j] = storage[i];
}`

You aren't updating the value for `i` in this loop, since, if you wanted to, I believe it would need to be right next to the `j++`. So, your loop keeps running and incrementing `j`, with `i` never changing, until you get to the end of the title array. Then you try to access memory the title array doesn't have, and there comes your Seg Fault.

Answer (score 2):

In this line :
`if(storage[i] = '<' && storage [i+1] = 't'){`

You are assinging `'<'` to `storage[i]`. Change it to `if(storage[i] == '<' && storage [i+1] == 't'){` to check for equality.

Also in `for(i=0; storage[i]; i++)` it's better to iterate until (`<`) the number of bytes read. [fread()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/) returns the number of elements successfully read. If the the contents of the file are not read you are checking existing values in the array which are not initialised. You should use `memset()` to initialize the array to 0.

As it currently stands, if you go past the size of `BUFLEN` with the `[i+1]` index, you'll be reading outside the allocated memory for the array. You can also go past the number of bytes read and check something that wasn't read and/or initialised.

Comment: sorry about the fuss about '=' and '==', i was careless in copying the code.
i changing the repetition condition to what you said but i still keep getting the segmentation fault error

Comment: I'd say, forget about BUFLEN which solely limits the number of items read by fread(). The only measure for the number of read bytes in the storage array is the return value of fread(). Another problem arises if the title happens to be longer than 2k bytes (which isn't common, granted). Accessing `storage[i+1]` must be protected by checking if `i + 1`is smaller than the number of items read

Answer (score 1):

You have *undefined behavior* in your code, more specifically the condition `storage[i]` in your loop.

Local variables, including arrays, are not initialized, their values are *indeterminate*, and using those indeterminate values leads to undefined behavior. Using the condition `storage[i]` in the loop might even cause you to iterate out of bounds of the array.

You need to use the return value of [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) to know how many characters were read, and use that as an upper limit in the loop. And then you have to think about what happens with `storage [i+1]` when `i` is at the upper limit already.